# How do I share multiple chrome profiles between machines?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

Chrome allows creating additional user profiles. But for sync, you need an account. I sure have got one in my default Chrome profile. So, can I use it in these additional Chrome profiles as well? Will that work the way it works for the default profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can use several accounts. Each one can sync to a different address if you like but you can also leave the other accounts as *local*. We do this for when kids use the browser. It's also fine with multiple Google Accounts, if you have some for personal and some for work, it's a good way to separate the search history, account login cookies, etc.